# How do I send Arduino data to a HighChart using AsyncWebServer and AsyncEventSource library when the Arduino commands it?

Tags: highcharts

I collect the ticks produced by a GM tube using the interrupt facility of the ESP32. Increments a global integer called ticks.
A 60 second timer interrupt routine collects these ticks every minute exactly and resets the tick counter.
I need a way to send this data every minute to HighCharts for display.

**Here is what I've tried without success. **

```
.
.
<div class="content">
<div class= "ticks" id="chart-ticks"></div>
.
.
<script>
var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart:{ renderTo : 'chart-ticks' },
  title: { text: 'Rad ticks' },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: []
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: { animation: false,
      dataLabels: { enabled: true }
    },
    series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
  xAxis: { type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: '%H:%M:%S' }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: { text: 'Ticks per minute' }
  },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});
function updateTicks( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
      console.log("ticks:");
      console.log(this.responseText);
      if(chartT.series[0].data.length > 60) {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
      } else {
        chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
      }
    }
  };
}
.
.
source.addEventListener('ticks', function(e) {
  console.log("ticks", e.data);
  update_ticks();
 }, false);
```

**then call it from the ESP32 code like this;**

```
  if(MinuteHasPast){
    MinuteHasPast = false;
    events.send(String(Ticks).c_str(),"ticks",millis());
    Ticks = 0;
  }
```

No joy :(

## HELP

Comment: Hello! I recommend familiarizing yourself with the documentation for working with live data in Highcharts. You can findi t here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data. Additional demo example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/live-data